# How to find largest value,any of remaining max values and last remaining max value not used before

Tags: oracle

I need to use max_weight,max_height and max_volume using Oracle SQL 
as follows:

- Length = largest value of Max Height, Max Width or Max Depth
- Height = any of the remaining 2 max values
- Width = last remaining max value not used before

I have attached  basic query to get the max values but I need above filtered one data out of this.

How to write query in order to calculate the same

[image: sql query]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pyzqs.png)

Comment: What happens after they are Ranked?  Do they merely get multiplied together?  If so, it may be that their Rank does not matter??

Comment: Actually I need to store in database and show it to the user.

Comment: Please be specific about that output database.  What is the DDL? Column names and types?  As one row, or as three rows?

Comment: Why "using pl sql"? Very likely you are mis-using "pl" there; the code you are showing is plain "sql" (specifically, the Oracle dialect; that is called "Oracle SQL", not "PL/SQL").

Comment: Also: in your code snippet you create new values called MAX_WEIGHT, MAX_HEIGHT and MAX_VOLUME. What do those have to do with MAX_HEIGHT, MAX_WITDH and MAX_DEPTH? The question as currently written makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

In the mean time, you might work with this... run it to see what the results are, and then wrap it with and use Case When rmax = 1...

```
select 
    MAXNUM
    ,RANK() over( order by maxnum  desc)as rmax
    ,dim
from (
    select 
        2 as maxnum, 'weight' as dim
    union
    select  
        4 as maxnum, 'length' as dim
    union
    select
        8 as maxnum, 'height' as dim
) as nnn
```

Comment: can you please suggest how to wrap it up, also can I use greatest function as i am using plsql.

Comment: @user2997518 - you are NOT using PL/SQL (at least, you have not demonstrated that). In any case, you should indeed use GREATEST function, since your three numbers appear in the same row, not in a column as in the made-up data in the solution proposed here.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have the following data (the columns are labeled `col1`, `col2`, `col3` in my example; labeling them as "height" or "max_height" is pretty meaningless if the task is to determine WHICH of them is the "height" in each case).

```
  col1   col2   col3
------ ------ ------
    10      8     15
    11     11     30
    13      9      9
    15      7     15
```

And you want to rearrange the numbers in each ROW so that the output looks like this:

```
length height  width
------ ------ ------
    15     10      8
    30     11     11
    13      9      9
    15     15      7
```

Here is an efficient way to do it - you don't have to unpivot the inputs (to put all the numbers in one long column). It works because GREATEST can give you the length, LEAST can give you the width, and to get the middle one, you can add the three numbers and subtract the two extremes. This simplistic approach would NOT work if you had to rank four or more numeric attributes, but it works fine for three.

```
with
  test_data(col1, col2, col3) as(
    select 10,  8, 15 from dual union all
    select 11, 11, 30 from dual union all
    select 13,  9,  9 from dual union all
    select 15,  7, 15 from dual
  )
-- End of simulated data (not part of the solution).
-- SQL query begins BELOW THIS LINE. Use actual table and column names.
select col1, col2, col3,
       greatest(col1, col2, col3)                      as length,
       col1 + col2 + col3 - greatest(col1, col2, col3) 
                          - least(col1, col2, col3)    as height,
       least(col1, col2, col3)                         as width
from   test_data
;

      COL1       COL2       COL3     LENGTH     HEIGHT      WIDTH
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
        10          8         15         15         10          8
        11         11         30         30         11         11
        13          9          9         13          9          9
        15          7         15         15         15          7
```